# timeout delays the error callback execution in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request as following,

```
 $.ajax({
    url: scriptUrl,
    dataType: 'script',
    timeout: 6000,
    cache: true,
    success: function() {
        some code
    },                    
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        some code
    }
});
```

I use this to get branding template. & this template may or may not exist.
The problem is if it fails, i get the response in about 200ms, but my error callback gets invoked after 6sec or what ever time is set in the timeout.
But if the request is successfull, then it goes to the success callback as soon as the response is given. If I remove the timeout, none of the success or error callback gets executed.

The request is made to a CDN, & if the file doesn't exist on the server it returns a status code of 403.

My question is, How can i execute the error callback upon arrival of the response regardless of what ever timeout is set?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Try with `$.ajax({....}).done(function(){//success code here}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){//error code here})` and remove `success:` and `error:` from `.ajax`

Comment: Same as previous, taking 6 sec. If i remove the timeout none of done & fail get executed

Comment: do not remove `timeout`..

Comment: tried both the ways,with & with out timeout

Comment: One thing is to mention here, I am making request on the CDN. & if the template dosen't exist i get 403 status code. If the status code is 404, then   both Guruprasad Rao's approach & existing approach works.

Comment: **A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action.** Try keeping alert in `success` when you have `403` status code..